# ContextMenu shows item I have not specified in context_menu.xml

Tags: android, contextmenu

I'm an Android noob. I'm working with MyEclipse, ADT, SDK, Android 2.2, API 8.

My Activity looks like this -

```
package com.vvittal.relativelayout;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.widget.AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo;

public class Login extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    registerForContextMenu(findViewById(R.id.uEntry));
    registerForContextMenu(findViewById(R.id.pwdEntry));
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.login_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch (item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.agency_item: System.out.println("----------------"); 
    return true;
    case R.id.prod_cat_item: System.out.println("++++++++++++++++"); 
    return true;
    default: return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo){
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
    //menu.f
    //menu.setHeaderTitle("Your Options");
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.option1: ;
    return true;
    case R.id.option2:
        return true;
    default:
        int i = item.getItemId();
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
}
```

And my AndroidManifest.xml look like this -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.vvittal.relativelayout"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".Login"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
</manifest>
```

The context_menu.xml is as below -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/option1"
      android:title="@string/yes" />
<item android:id="@+id/option2"
      android:title="@string/no" />
</menu>
```

The menu on my emulator has an item called "Input Method", in addition to "Yes" and "No" that I have specified in XML.

I'd like to know where this additional item "Input Method" is coming from when I have not specified any in the xml? Also how to I remove it programmatically?

Comment: On which control fires the menu? Most probably the 'input method' is firing from EditText (or editable textView) by default.

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to know where this additional item "Input Method" is coming from when I have not specified any in the xml?

The operating system will add context menu choices as appropriate for the widget. In the case of `EditText` widgets, this will include things like cut, copy, paste, select all, and choosing an input method.

> Also how to I remove it programmatically?

Please don't. First, they are there to help the user. Second, they are standard for the platform, and users may get irritated if they are not available.

Comment: Thanks commonsWare and xandy. What is the difference between a long press and short press menu? What I've noticed on the emulator is that if I press and hold the mouse on the EditText I get the context menu, but if I press EditText for a short time then the system just displays a softkeypad. Also, I'm not going to production with this code yet, I'm far, far away from it. I'm just reading the "Menu" section of the tutorial and wanted to add a Context Menu for one of the Views.

Comment: @sledge_hammer: There is no "short press menu". If an `EditText` gets the focus, and there is no hardware keyboard, the soft keyboard appears.

Comment: Thanks much! I'd like to get under the hood and try to see if I can understand how Adnroid knows to provide certain menu items for certain views/widgets. Does it reply on Intents to insert the menu item for the View that I define?

Comment: @sledge_hammer: No, it relies on inheritance.